# Pass Subject and Description in new Case

Tags: apex, trigger, case, update, after-trigger

I have an after insert trigger that is updating cases and I want to be able to pass Subject and Description on with casesToUpdate. Below is the code. I do not want to change the Subject or Description I just want to pass it on so another class can use that info.

```
    trigger CaseReassignQueueBasedOnSubject on Case (after insert) {
Map<String, List<Id>> CNUMToCaseId = new Map<String, List<Id>>();
String CNUM = null;
String CaseId = null;

//Parse out all of the CNUM
for (Case c : trigger.new) {
    if (c.Subject.contains('[')) {
        Integer start_pos = c.Subject.indexOf('[') + 1;
        Integer end_pos = c.Subject.indexOf(']',start_pos);
        CNUM = c.Subject.substring(start_pos,end_pos);
        CaseId = c.Id;

        if (!CNUMToCaseId.containsKey(CNUM)) {
            CNUMToCaseId.put(CNUM, new List<Id>());
        }
        System.debug('Parsed_CNUM: ' + CNUM);
        CNUMToCaseId.get(CNUM).add(caseId);
    }
}

//Get List of all assets that match the CNUM
List<Asset> assets = [
    SELECT Id, CNUM__C, AccountId
    FROM Asset
    WHERE CNUM__c IN :CNUMToCaseId.keySet()
];

List<Case> casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();
//Set case to closed and assign to correct Account/Asset/Department(topic)
for (Asset a : assets) {
    for (id i : CNUMToCaseId.get(a.CNUM__c)) {
        Case cToUpdate = new Case(
            Id = i,
            Status = 'Closed',
            Topic__c = 'Software_Support',
            AccountId = a.AccountId,
            AssetId = a.Id
        );
        casesToUpdate.add(cToUpdate);
    }
}

//Update Cases
System.debug('casesToUpdate: ' + casesToUpdate.size());
if (casesToUpdate.size() > 0) {
    update casesToUpdate;
    try {
        System.debug('casesToUpdate: ' + casesToUpdate);
        DB_EditObjectCreationCaseDeletion.CreateDBObjectDeleteCase(casesToUpdate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('Exception Error Message: ' + e);
    }
}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by having another class use the information? What class? Is it part of your trigger handler, another trigger, a separate utility class...?

Comment: David, In the update sequence of events I check to see if case needs to be deleted and it is based on the subject. If the subject matches it will delete it but It will create a custom object first with the subject and description data

I have added the code to the bottom of the original post

Comment: David, I am not sure if I follow. When it gets to `Case cToUpdate = new Case(...` I don't have anything from the previous case besides the ID and CNUM

Comment: I apologize; my comment was unclear because I wrote the wrong word. I meant to say "could you add that information to your *question* via an edit?" Looks like you've already done that, however. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Sorry about the confusion. It is at the bottom. It was too long for the comment :)

Comment: Your question needs some more details.  Is this after insert trigger on the Case itself?  What is `CNUMToCaseId`?   Please include that declaration in your code.

Comment: @DavidCheng I have added the entire trigger for you you. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `Trigger.newMap` here. It's typed as a `Map<Id, sObject>` for whatever sObject this trigger is running on.

When you create your new Cases:

```
for (id i : CNUMToCaseId.get(a.CNUM__c)) {
    Case cToUpdate = new Case(
        Id = i,
        Status = 'Closed',
        Topic__c = 'Software_Support',
        AccountId = a.AccountId,
        AssetId = a.Id
    );
    casesToUpdate.add(cToUpdate);
}
```

You can add parameters to `new Case` along the lines of

```
Subject = Trigger.newMap.get(i).Subject
```

for whichever fields you want to access. Since the Id values you're iterating over all come from the trigger's object set anyway, you don't need to worry about nulls in that map access.

I'm not sure of the purpose behind updating the Cases before you delete them. Unless you have `after update` trigger behavior or processes/workflow rules keyed on these updates, it's just a waste of CPU time. If you just need those values to be provided to `DB_EditObjectCreationCaseDeletion.CreateDBObjectDeleteCase()`, you don't need to persist them to the database.

Comment: Perfect! This exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much @David Reed!